# Calculating the Recurrence Relation T(n)=T(n / [(log n)^2]) + Θ(1)

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, complexity-theory, recurrence

I tried to solve this problem many hours and I think the solution is O(log n/[log (log n)^2]). but I'm not sure.Is this solution correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand the equation:

```
T(n) = (T(n/(log^2(n)*log(n/log^2(n))^2) + Theta(1)) Theta(1) = 
        T(n/(log^4(n) + 4 (loglog(n))^2 - 4log(n)loglog(n)) + 2 * Theta(1)
```

We know `n/(log^4(n) + 4 (log(log(n)))^2 - 4log(n)log(log(n))` is greater than `n/log^4(n)` asymptotically. As you can see, each time `n` is divided by `log^2(n)`. Hence, we can say if we compute the height of dividing `n` by `log^2(n)` up to reaching to 1, it will be a lower bound for `T(n)`.

Hence, the height of the expansion tree will be `k` such that

```
n = (log^2(n))^k = lof^2k(n) =>‌ (take a log) 
    log(n) = 2k log(log(n)) => k = log(n)/(2 * log(log(n)))
```

Therefore, `T(n) = Omega(log(n)/log(log(n)))`.

For the upper bound, as we know that `n/(i-th statement) <‌ n/log^i(n)` (instead of applying `log^2(n)`, we've applied `log(n)`), we can say the height of division of `n` by `log(n)` will be an upper bound for `T(n)`. Hence, as:

```
n = log^k(n) => log(n) = k log(log(n)) => k = log(n) / log(log(n))
```

we can say `T(n) = O(log(n) / log(log(n)))`.

Comment: we know that order of T(n)=T(n/log n)+O(1) is O(log n/log log n). according to your prove T(n)=T(n/[log n]^c)+O(1) is  O(log n/log log n).(c is a constant) right?

Comment: @erfan30 indeed.